# Insert Picture beginning from the margin

Tags: diagrams, margins, text

the template of my university has a 2,5cm margin for text.
My Picture should have 0.1mm from margin. ( for example )

Google says, it is possible with minimap, but my code didn't help.
How can I "break" the margin rule for the picture?

for example: the black boxes are the text and the blue box is the picture
[image: for example: the black boxes are the text and the blue box is the picture]

```
 \begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
 \vspace{5mm}
 %\centering
 \includegraphics[width=1.4\linewidth]{gfx/Upload/checkTodoSchwodo.png}
 \caption{Quelle: Selbsterstellt}
 \label{fig:checkTodoSchwodo}
 \vspace{5mm}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX:SE!

I guess that you looking for something like this:

[image]

(red lines show page layout)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{Quelle: Selbsterstellt}
\label{fig:checkTodoSchwodo}
\end{adjustwidth*}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Adendum:**
Or you may be interested for the following solution, where is used `copyright` package for denote source of image and has standard caption:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex,
            font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
\copyrightbox[b]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}
                {Quelle: Selbsterstellt}
\caption{May big image}
\label{fig:checkTodoSchwodo}
\end{adjustwidth*}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]